# Como verificar se a duplicata em query SQL e utilizar outra coluna para escolher qual ira para querie final

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela preços e uma tabela item, a mais de um preço para cada item e preciso pegar apenas aquele com valor mais baixo.

```sql
SELECT `nameItem`,`descItem`,`valuePrice`,`datePrice` FROM item, price WHERE item.idItem = price.fk_idItem
```

Esta querie retorna todos eles.

Comment: Olá viva, coloca no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) o teu exemplo de tabelas e aí sim, terás melhor ajuda. Contudo, uma [dica](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_min.asp), tens aqui a documentação da função MIN() de mysql. Poderá ser uma opção, existem várias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `nameItem`, `descItem`, MIN(`valuePrice`), `datePrice` 
FROM item, price 
WHERE item.idItem = price.fk_idItem
GROUP BY `nameItem`, `descItem`
```

Comment: Apenas lembrando que a existência de um campo na lista de seleção que não se encontra nem na lista do GROUP BY nem em uma função de agregação não é aceita em todos os SGBD. No MySQL é permitido se ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY estiver desabilitada.